# How to forward only *.jsp or *.do requests to Tomcat using mod_proxy?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I am using mod_proxy module to forward all requests for one of my domain to be served by Tomcat. However I want to forward only requests ending *.jsp or *.do or *.something to Tomcat and rest (e.g. *.html, *.php, *.png) to be served by Apache server. How to achieve that using **mod_proxy**?

Following is sample httpd.conf config that I am using currently:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /  ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: OK I found it finally, answer is ProxyPassMatch

Answer (score 0):

I know that you had found the answer but I write this answer for others that maybe need it:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    #ProxyPass         /  ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.do)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.jsp)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1
```