# TOMCAT angular app cannot connect to node.js server - how to rig up proxy?

Tags: node.js, angular, tomcat

SUBJECT
TOMCAT angular app  cannot connect to node.js server - how to rig up proxy?

Hi fellow angulars

when I run my angular app using ng serve my proxy.conf.json is built in
my node.js JSON api server is serving up models
and all runs fine

So I decided to deploy to tomcat
APP runs fine but cannot connect to the running node.js server

Does anyone know what the config procedure is to get tomcat to proxy http thru to my node.js server ?

below is my proxy.conf.json

angular-cli isnt cutting it

and like I said I am just dangling my angular app off the tomcat doc root

ThANKS IN ADVANCE

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Comment: i cannot find any docs on this and any other means seems overkill for just a mere json config file

Comment: so instead of using `ng serve` you deploy your app to a tomcat server, but the node.js backend server will still be the same, is that correct?

Comment: correct... works when I operate ng serve... ONLY

Comment: so question remains... how do we configure a node.js server on a tomcat angular app... it is only runnable with angular-cli  ng serve ONLY

Comment: here are my package.json run commands respectively for client and server

Comment: "client": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --no-delete-output-path",
        "server": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/server/server.ts",

Comment: angular-cli likes the proxy-config so I need to know how to do same for tomcat

Comment: Exactly, ng serve just proxy tunnels specific request to the node server. I'm not a tomcat guy, so I can't really help you with that but there are probably some tutorials out there how to proxy specific requests to a different server in tomcat. There's also probably something like a conf file that does the job. Your question title probably does not exactly hint to what you're actually needing. But if no one can answer your question here directly, I'm sure there's a similar question on stack

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/14515708/5634712](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14515708/5634712) this might help you out. It's called ProxyPassMatch I think

Comment: thanks friend... i did java for 16 years so im thinking there must be a servlet somewhere turnkey out of the box to rig up. I found this and wondering if it will do the trick  https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: well Im not a tomcat topology expert in proxying but I have a slew of web pages currently running on TOMCAT and I deployed my angular client on it its runnign fine but I just need to proxy a tunnel into my koa2 node.js rest friendly json mongodb database and so my node.js server is heavily fortified for database back end models and such. I just want to snap it all together with a proxy. other web posts say you cannot embed a node.js server in tomcat its redundant but I have a reasonable use case... for at least proxy/forward/redirect.

Comment: The node-http-proxy library (which is now http-proxy) is ONLY for standalone node.js servers and doesnt snap into TOMCAT. Any other ideas or help is appreciated... less code is better

Comment: [https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks Benedict friend I will give that a try when I get a chance - cheers !